# Calculation of Cartier-Manin matrix

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algorithms, algebraic-curves, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ and let $C$ be a plane projective nonsingular curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ ,
with function field $K = \mathbb{F}_q(C)$. Let $K^p$ denote the subfield of $p$-th powers and choose a separable generating transcendental element $x \in K \setminus K^p$.

Denote with $\Omega(K)$ the $K$-vector space of differentials, then every
differential $\omega \in \Omega(K)$ can be written uniquely as $\omega = d \lambda + a^px^{p-1}dx$ with $\lambda, a \in K$.

The Cartier operator $\mathcal{C}: \Omega(K) \to \Omega(K)$ is defined as $\mathcal{C}(x) = a dx$.

Let $(\omega_1 , \ldots , \omega_g)$
be a basis of $\Omega^0(K)$, then there exists a $g × g$ matrix $A = (a_{i,j} )$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_q$ such that 
$$\mathcal{C} \begin{pmatrix}
\omega_1 \\
\vdots \\
\omega_g  \\
\end{pmatrix} = A^{(\frac{1}{p})}\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_1 \\
\vdots \\
\omega_g  \\
\end{pmatrix}, \text{ where } A^{(\frac{1}{p})} \text{ denotes } (a_{i,j}^{\frac{1}{p}} ),$$ 
see [Yu. I. Manin, 1961](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3370&option_lang=eng).

The matrix $A$ is called the Cartier–Manin matrix. My question is about a calculation of this matrix (for some $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_g$). If $C$ is a hyperelliptic curve then there is an effective algorithm for this - that works in time $poly(g, p, \log q)$ - see [Handbook of elliptic and hyperelliptic curve cryptography, pg. 412](http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ccs130h/2013/EllipticHyperelliptic-CohenFrey.pdf).

Is there an effective algorithm of calculation of $A$ for an arbitrary $C$?

Comment: K.O. Stöhr, J. F. Voloch, A formula for the Cartier operator on plane algebraic curves. J. Reine Angew. Math. 377(1987), 49-64.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch That looks more like an answer than a comment!

Comment: @JoeSilverman Thanks! The paper in my comment gives a formula and a way to calculate the Cartier-Manin matrix (aka Hasse-Witt matrix) for any curve, given a (possibly singular) plane model. But I don't know if it can be turned into an algorithm with the same running time as the one cited in the question.

Comment: This is also partially addressed in J. Gonzalez, "Hasse-Witt Matrices For The Fermat Curves Of Prime Degree" Tohoku Math J, 1997

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Could you answer a simpler question: if somebody will give us this matrix ( and a basis), could we verify that it is indeed the Cartier-Manin for this basis in time poly($p, \log q, g)$?

Comment: @Alexey I think the main problem is how is the curve given to you. If I have a plane model and a basis for the regular differentials in terms of this plane model ("adjoint curves") then the formula in my paper with Stöhr might have the running time you want (I haven't checked details, but it shouldn't be hard). But the purely geometric question of putting the curve in the right form and computing the adjoints is something I don't know much about, so I can't really say how easy or hard it is.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch if our curve is plane (it is given as $f(x,y)=0$) can we chose a suitable basis for the regular differentials?

Comment: @Alexey Do you know the singularities?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Do you mean the singularities of $f(x, y) =0$? Let us assume that we know.

Comment: @Alexey Yes, I meant the singularities of $f=0$. If the singularities are nice (e.g. double points) then it's an easy linear algebra problem. If they are complicated, I don't know.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch so, for such class of plane curves (where we understand that singularities are nice) we can find in poly$(g, \log q, p)$ time Cartier-Manin matrix and hence we can find  the number of rational points on its modulo $p$! This is interesting.